# Grab current users "admin" attribute from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Users model that has a field which is admin. This field is a boolean. I only want a user who is an admin (admin field = true) to be able to create a "Season." How on earth would I do this on rails? I don't even know where to start. I assume that in my application controller I could define "current_user_admin" and in my view use "current_user_admin?" to show the "create season" link. But what do I do in the model?

I do have current_user defined as such in my application_controller:

```
@current_user ||=User.find_by id: session[:user_id] if session[:user_id]
```

Am I going down the right path? Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: You can use `@current_user.admin?` in your controller and views for any action that ensures a logged in user (session) is present. If you cannot say if a user is present, you can use `@current_user.try(:admin?)` instead. Another common approach is to define a guest user model that will be assigned on default or replaced by a given user if logged in.

Comment: That worked!! Wow that was much easier than I thought! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would only allow to load users that have the `admin` flag set on routes like that:

```
@current_admin ||= User.find_by(
  id: session[:user_id], admin: true
) if session[:user_id]
```

Comment: That's a good point. In my routes I have   resources :seasons do resources :danceclasses end. I don't want seasons#new to load unless you have that admin flag. Where wouldn't I put that log you've pasted? Seasons Controller?